# Why is my hashable object not found in a set of that hashable object, the set being an attribute of another object?

Tags: python, list, hash, set, hashable

I have a recursive relationship between objects of two classes: `Foo` has a `set` of `Bar` objects (in its `bars` attribute) and every `Bar` has a `list` of `Foo` objects (in its `foos` attribute). I've implemented is as shown in the MWE below, but the test fails. Why?

According to the [Python Glossary](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-hashable), a `set` can only contain `hashable` objects and `hashable` objects:

> An object is `hashable` if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()` method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an `__eq__()` method).

I don't really know if my MWE below satisfies that the objects have a hash that never changes, because the hash depends on the the other object(s) in the list and set attributes. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Minimal working example:

```
import unittest


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo_bar(self):
        foo = Foo()
        bar = Bar()
        bar.add_foo(foo)

        print(bar)
        print(foo.bars)
        print(hash(bar))
        for bar in foo.bars:
            print(hash(bar))
        # The previous print lines print the following:
        # <mwe2.Bar object at 0x105ba8080>
        # {<mwe2.Bar object at 0x105ba8080>}
        # -9223096319794529578
        # -9223096319794529578

        # The following assertion is OK
        self.assertTrue(bar in {bar})

        # The following assertion fails with AssertionError: False is not true
        self.assertTrue(bar in foo.bars)



class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bars = set()

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(self.__dict__.values())


class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foos = list()

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(tuple(self.foos))

    def add_foo(self, foo: "Foo"):
        foo.bars.add(self)
        self.foos.append(foo)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I use CPython, Python 3.6.x.

Comment: Generally speaking: a hashable object *should* be immutable, or at least its hash should be stable and not depend on mutable properties. The hash of your objects changes over time, which is Not Good™️.

Comment: For me the `add` call works. Why shouldn't it work?

Comment: Ah, my bad. See, too confusing! ;)

Comment: So now you understand my confusion too! ;)

Comment: The answer is probably somewhere in how mutable hashes go against the assumptions made by the internals of `set`. Hence the problem is probably the fact that your hashes mutate.

Comment: @Erik: frankly you could reduce your code a lot. And no need for type hints and all for non python 3.6 users. I would drop the unitest part. Just print the results...

Comment: are `hash(bar)`s legal in your country?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, the code is not truly minimal, but I reduced it from a large file until I had this left, so that's why there's some noise in the example. And yes, hash bars are legal here. ;)

Comment: @Erik can you check `bar in {bar}` again? because it _works_. The first test doesn't because of reasons explained by deceze & the answer, but the simple case works fine for anyone but you. Time to [edit] it out?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre , indeed, it works. My bad, you're right! I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `Bar`'s hash changes immediately after you add it to `Foo.bars`. You can see this if you add some `print` statements in the `add_foo` method:

```
def add_foo(self, foo: "Foo"):
    foo.bars.add(self)
    print(hash(self))
    self.foos.append(foo)
    print(hash(self))
```

Output:

```
3527539
957074234
```

This is because the hash is calculated based on `self.foos`, so any modification of `self.foos` also changes the object's hash.

(Side note: Contrary to what's stated in the question, `bar in {bar}` evaluates to `True` as you'd expect. There is no reason why it wouldn't. I suspect that there was some kind of mistake while debugging.)

---

A simple way to make the unittest work is to swap the two lines of code in `add_foo`:

```
def add_foo(self, foo: "Foo"):
    self.foos.append(foo)  # append first
    foo.bars.add(self)  # add to the set with the new hash
```

Output:

```
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

However, this isn't a real fix: It won't help if you call `add_foo` more than once. If you ever call `add_foo` after adding a `Bar` object to a set or a dict, you'll get the same problem again.

I think it's clear that having interdependent classes with inconsistent hashes is a bad design choice. Possible solutions include

1. Removing the `Foo` -> `Bar` -> `Foo` dependency cycle
2. Finding a consistent hash method

Comment: that explains the first failed assertion. but not `bar in {bar}` (don't try to explain that, because it works for me :))

Comment: Thanks. This answer and the comments on my question lead me to the conclusion that for my use case I need to remove the cyclic dependency.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I just realized that the whole `bar in {bar}` thing is even in the question title... so I guess I should either address it in my answer or edit it out, because it's really not reproducible with these classes.

Comment: but there's nothing to address: it _works_. OP should edit it out.